# Difference between 看作 and 看成

Tags: grammar

Recently， I've been listening to a chinese podcast and in the podcast I heard someone say "中国人常常把谦虚看作一种美德“。  I have also heard the term “叫作” within the podcast - I'm wondering, is there a clear difference between this and 看成／ 教程？

Answer (score 8):

看作, 看成

- be seen as

叫作

- be said as

---

The explanation is only the literal interpretation. Despite of the difference described above, both of them carry similar underlying meanings:

1. be comprehended as
2. be classified as

We can dissect the sentence "中国人常常把谦虚看作一种美德" as follows:

1. 中国人

   - Chinese people
2. 常常

   - Usually (Always)
3. 把

   - (This one will be discussed later)
4. 谦虚

   - Humility
5. 看作

   - Be seen as
6. 一种

   - A kind of
7. 美德

   - Virtue

---

Without reordering the phrases, you can come up with the following sentence:

```
Chinese people always (*) humility be seen as a kind of virtue.
```

I bet you know the meaning of this sentence. Though it sounds a bit weird.

**Note**

- In short, the presence of "把" indicates the use of "passive voice" in the above sentence (Humility is always being comprehended as a virtue by Chinese people.).
- If you are interested in the detailed explanation of the usage of "把", [this page](http://www.ctcfl.ox.ac.uk/Grammar%20exercises/Ba.htm) should give you a concrete understanding on this topic.

---

p.s. "教程" means course/tutorial.

Comment: I think it is really useful the way you broke down the sentence and hope you continue with this method. Please check some of my other questions on my profile and I will appreciate it very much, if you have time, to provide some additional insights.

Comment: @TommieC. Thanks for your support! Your other questions have all already been answered very well though!

Comment: For the most part you are correct, however there are two open questions without accepted answers that could benefit from a native speaker. In any case, keep up the good work.

Comment: 常常 is more like "usually" than "always"

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the question in the title was never addressed:

**看作**

> VARIANT OF 看做 kànzuò
>
> look upon as; regard as
>
> 你把次要问题看做主要问题了。
>
> Nǐ bǎ cìyao wèntí kànzuò zhǔyào wèntí le.
>
> You have taken a minor question for a major one.
>
> 他把别人的困难看做是自己的困难。
>
> Tā bǎ biéren de kùnnan kànzuò shì zìjǐ de kùnnan.
>
> He looks upon the problems of other people as his own.

**看成**

> 1 take sb. or sth. for; look upon as; regard as
>
> 你把我看成什么人了？
>
> Nǐ bǎ wǒ kàn chéng shénme rén le？
>
> What do you take me for?
>
> 我把十块的票子看成五块的了。
>
> Wǒ bǎ shí kuài de piàozi kànchéng wǔ kuài de le.
>
> I mistook the ten-yuan bill for a five-yuan one.
>
> 2 be able to see or watch
>
> 我有会, 电影没看成。
>
> Wǒ yǒu huì, diànyǐng méi kàn chéng.
>
> I had a meeting and wasn't able to see the film.

So although the two words are similar and setimes interchangeable but there are still different contexts to consider.